# app script error when running from Document UI

Tags: google-apps-script

After IO last week, I added an option to the UI of a document to migrate meetings from yesterday's minutes table to today's.

The script runs fine when i debug or run in the script editor, however, when i run from the UI, i get an error saying function has experienced an error. An error has occurred and we cannot save your changes.

[Screen capture of error](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B5_QEt8LPH5dZEViUEEzT1lsNkk/edit?usp=sharing)

Below is my code:

```
function onOpen() {
  var UI = DocumentApp.getUi();
  UI.createMenu("StandUp").addItem("Migrate Yesterday", DoMigrate).addToUi();  
}

function DoMigrate(){

var dater =new Date();  
var weekday=new Array(7);
weekday[0]="Sunday";
weekday[1]="Monday";
weekday[2]="Tuesday";
weekday[3]="Wednesday";
weekday[4]="Thursday";
weekday[5]="Friday";
weekday[6]="Saturday";

var month=new Array(12);
month[0]="January";
month[1]="Febuary";
month[2]="March";
month[3]="April";
month[4]="May";
month[5]="June";
month[6]="July";
month[7]="August";
month[8]="Sept";
month[9]="Oct";
month[10]="Nov";
month[11]="Dec";

var dayOfWeek = weekday[dater.getDay()];
var theMonth = month[dater.getMonth()];
  var paragraph = dayOfWeek + ", " + theMonth + " " + dater.getDate() + ", " + dater.getFullYear();
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();

  var tables = doc.getTables();

  var latestTable = tables[0].copy();

  for (var i = 1; i < 8.; i++)
  {
      var todayWork = latestTable.getCell(i,2).getText();

      var yesterdayCell = latestTable.getCell(i,1);
      var todayCell = latestTable.getCell(i,2);

      yesterdayCell.clear()          

      var listCount = todayCell.getNumChildren();

      for(var x = 0; x < listCount; x++)
      {
         var listText = todayCell.getChild(x).asText().getText();
         yesterdayCell.appendListItem(listText).setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.BULLET);
      }

      todayCell.clear();


      todayCell.appendListItem("").setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.BULLET);
  }

  doc.insertTable(0, latestTable) 
  doc.getBody().insertParagraph(0, paragraph).setBold(true).setFontSize(12);
  doc.saveAndClose();
}
```

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: Sorry I missed out on some code:

Comment: Looks like I was missing quotes around the function name to call in the AddItem line of the onOpen.

Answer (score 1):

After some feedback on the google plus community, it turns out i was missing quotes around the function name in my onLoad.

UI.createMenu("StandUp").addItem("Migrate Yesterday", DoMigrate).addToUi();

should have been

UI.createMenu("StandUp").addItem("Migrate Yesterday", "DoMigrate").addToUi();